# Is there a limit for number terms that can be associated to a document

Tags: document-library, taxonomy, metadata

I have a document library with documents. I need to associate the documents  to terms in a terms store. 
I have added a managed meta data column.

Is there a limit to the number of terms that can be assoociated to one document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first Managed Metadata field added to a list is allocated four columns:
>
> - A lookup field for the actual tag
> - A hidden text field for the string value
> - A lookup field for the catch all
> - A lookup field for spillover of the catch all
>
> Each subsequent Managed Metadata field added to a list adds two more columns:
>
> - A lookup field for the actual tag
> - A hidden text field for the string value
>
> The maximum number of columns of Managed Metadata is calculated as (14 + (16 * (n-1))) where n is the row mapping value (default of 6).

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx

Comment: The maximum no of metadata columns is 94 is so are you saying only 1502 terms can be assosicated to a document